# Docker: Invalid connection string

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to setup a NodeJS and MongoDB container.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: newsarg-api
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

This is my mongodb connection:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/newsarg-api", { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log("Connection Successful"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

const connection = mongoose.connection

connection.once('open', function(){
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established!')
})
```

And this is the error that I'm receiving:
[image]

From what I can tell, this is exactly what the connection should look like with MongoDB.

I also tried to change the connection to the production connection, which works, and I still receive the same error, so I'm not sure if it goes deeper than the connection.

Edit: this is the exact error that I receive:

```
newsarg-api | > backend@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
newsarg-api | > node app.js
newsarg-api | 
newsarg-api | Server is running on Port: 3000
newsarg-api | (node:19) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
newsarg-api |     at parseConnectionString (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:507:21)
newsarg-api |     at connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:266:3)
newsarg-api |     at ConnectOperation.execute (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:191:5)
newsarg-api |     at executeOperation (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:83:26)
newsarg-api |     at MongoClient.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:216:10)
newsarg-api |     at Promise (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:632:12)
newsarg-api |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
newsarg-api |     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:629:19)
newsarg-api |     at Mongoose.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:328:15)
newsarg-api |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app.js:40:10)
newsarg-api |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
newsarg-api |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
newsarg-api |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
newsarg-api |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
newsarg-api |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
newsarg-api |     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
newsarg-api | (node:19) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
newsarg-api | (node:19) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: If your application prints out an image file, usually that's a sign that it's running successfully.  You said it produces an error; can you edit the question to include the actual text of the error message, as text, in the question itself?

Comment: @DavidMaze I just added an edit in the post to show the error. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I completely removed all the associated containers, volumes, and images; once I did that, I ran docker-compose up, and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `links` in your app container? When you use docker-compose, base of [this document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) each containers will be join to same network, so you can use container name instead of the ip.

I have another question, do you want use your mongo container outside of your service? If not, you don't need publish the mongodb port `27017`, because two container are joined to same network.

So, I guess small change in your `docker-compose.yml` will be soled your problem:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: newsarg-api
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```